# I can't run Android Emulator

Tags: android-studio, sdk, amd-processor

I have hard time before starting application development.
I found I can't run HAXM in AMD, but instead I can use Android Emulator hypervisor driver for AMD.
But in my SDK tools, I can't find it.

Instead I have just Android Emulator hypervisor driver, but it does not help me to run emulator.
I already enabled Windows Hypervisor Platform and also CPU Virtualization from BIOS.
How can I install that, or I will just choose not to use emulator instead my phone.